# Python: Formatting a Pandas dataframe head with LaTex

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook, latex

I have made a Pandas dataframe from several NumPy arrays and tried to format columns heads using LaTex, but it looks awful. I'm working with Jupyter Notebook.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

Arrays (one instance out of five) look like this:

```
coeficientes = [0.5601, 0.3315, 0.2260, 0.1429, 0.0695]
coeficientes = np.array(coeficientes)
```

The dataframe:

```
tabla_resumen = pd.DataFrame({'$x_{n-i+1}$': submuestra1, 
                              '$x_{i}$': submuestra2, 
                              '$x_{n-i+1} - x_{i}$': diferencias, 
                              '$a_{n-i+i}$': coeficientes,
                              '$(x_{n-i+1} - x_{i})(a_{n-i+i})$': sumandos
                             })
tabla_resumen
```

The way it looks:

[image]

Are there any formatting options to make it look better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

## Function to convert to subscript

```
def get_sub(x):
    normal = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+-=()"
    sub_s = "ₐ₈CDₑբGₕᵢⱼₖₗₘₙₒₚQᵣₛₜᵤᵥwₓᵧZₐ♭꜀ᑯₑբ₉ₕᵢⱼₖₗₘₙₒₚ૧ᵣₛₜᵤᵥwₓᵧ₂₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉₊₋₌₍₎"
    res = x.maketrans(''.join(normal), ''.join(sub_s))
    return x.translate(res)
```

## Display subscript

```
print('H{}SO{}'.format(get_sub('2'),get_sub('4'))) #H₂SO₄
```

Comment: I get some kind of ASCII table using `to_latex()`. Documentation says "Requires \usepackage{booktabs}": where do I have to run that command?

Comment: @JavierBlanco No, you do not need that package and you can use this function instead of Pandas to_latex(), If you want to use Latex syntax with subscript in your Python code.

Comment: So there's no way to -properly- use LaTex within a dataframe?

Comment: @JavierBlanco To the best of my knowledge, unfortunately, there is no thorough way. So the combination of such functions may help you. You also can use "pandas.DataFrame.to_latex" to get the dataframe in the form of a latex document which you can open as a separate file. Did you try this function inside dataframe and then export it to latex code via "pandas.DataFrame.to_latex"?

Comment: I think I'm going to use plain text. It doesn't worth the effort. But thanks a lot for your time and your answer.